# Gigantic ant planet novel

Tags: story-identification

Looking for a sci fi novel written many years ago. It takes place on a planet inhabited by gigantic ants. There are four groups of humans called alpha humans who work for the ants. The groups are marked by having their hand encrusted by 'gems' created by the ants. Maybe 'chitin-ed hands'? There are also beta humans. Can anyone help with the name of this book?

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [Serpent's Reach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serpent%27s_Reach) by C. J. Cherryh, published 1980.

> It takes place on a planet inhabited by gigantic ants.

The Majat are an insectoid race, ant-like in appearance and behaviour.

> There are four groups of humans called alpha humans who work for the ants.

Four separate hives of Majat exist. Only the Kontrin family, the ruling class, have direct contact with the Majat.

> The groups are marked by having their hand encrusted by 'gems' created by the ants. Maybe 'chitin-ed hands'?

Each member of the Kontrin family has a chitinous mark on his or her hand, the Hive Jewel.

> There are also beta humans.

The common people in Serpents Reach are called Betas.