# Female feudal warlord allied with ant queen

Tags: story-identification, novel

Female hero in conflict with surrounding warlords. Has a human astronaut as a lover. Discovers human-sized ants on her property and forms tentative alliance.

Comment: I sure as hell hope you're not making this up because with this description I absolutely have to read this story.

Comment: Welcome to the site! When did you read this novel? How long was it? Where was it set? Can you remember any names? What language was it written in? I'm *sure* you remember at least some more details than this :-) See also [our guidance for asking story-ID questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31394).

Comment: As one example of how you could tell us more about the setting: Did the female hero grow up with, let's say, "Medieval Technology," or do her people know all about space travel, etc., before this particular human astronaut comes along? (Come to think of it, if you hadn't said "Astronaut," I could almost think you were remembering *Daughter of the Empire* by Raymond Feist and Janny Wurts. That heroine fell in love with a man from another world, but he'd come through a "rift" instead of flying in a spaceship.)

Comment: Daughter of the Empire was my first thought as well

Comment: Maybe "Serpent's Reach"? This question reminded me of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/105904/95523

Answer (score 4):

[The Empire Trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empire_Trilogy) by Raymond E. Feist and Janny Wurts.

> Female hero in conflict with surrounding warlords.

Mara of the Acoma is the ruling Lady of House Acoma.  Her house has many enemies, including House Minwanabi and House Anasati.  The latter she deals with by forming a political marriage with a member of House Anasati.

> Has a human astronaut as a lover

Rifts allow travel to other realms, one of which is Midkemia (as seen in Feist's other fantasy novels).  Mara buys a group of Midkemian prisoners of war to use as slaves.  One of them, Kevin, she falls in love with, and has a child with.

> Discovers human-sized ants on her property and forms tentative
>   alliance.

The cho-ja are an insectoid people, and are valuable allies.  When a new colony appears, Mara negotiates an alliance with the Queen to add their military power to her own.